# Invalid Argument when bind mount for Android

Tags: android, bind, mount

when use mount(".","/","",MS_BIND,NULL)

returns invalid argument error.

Is that MS_BIND cannot use in android? Besides there is no --bind option for android mount shell command.

Comment: I see the same problem: `mount -o bind / /foo` returns *invalid argument error*.  It works fine for other mount points but refuses to work on /, and I'd love to know why (better yet, how to work around the problem).

Answer (score 0):

There is a `--bind` option, except it is `-o bind`.